# failing to install JDK 7

Tags: java, macos, javafx, java-7

I don't know if it is the right place to ask, if not tell me I will migrate my question elsewhere.

I am using OSX (Maverick) and I am trying to install the JDK 7 in order to use javaFX. So I downloaded the `.dmg` package from oracle and when I double click on the package, I get the error message `can't found mountable file systems`. In the documentation I found this alert:

`If you download Java 7, you will not be able to run Java content in Chrome on Mac OS X and will need to use a 64-bit browser (such as Safari or Firefox) to run Java content within a browser. Additionally, installing Java 7 will disable the ability to use Apple Java 6 on your system.`

So how can I properly install the JDK 7? and Is it dangerous to install it? Could it mess up all my settings, knowing that I only want to use the JDK 7 to run some java project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error message you are getting just indicated a corrupt dmg file.
Try downloading and installing it again and it should work fine.

> So how can I properly install the JDK 7?

You can only install the 64bit version of Java 7, the only real downside is that it will not work with things like the crome browser, you can install it the same way as you first tried, download and install it from here: [JDK Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

> Is it dangerous to install it? Could it mess up all my settings

No, installing the JDK should not make any noticeable change, even if you run apps on it instead of your previous JDK/jar, they should still work. If you have older JDK's installed you can still use/select them in an IDE. If you do use crome then it should continue to work as normal using the existing/old JRE/JDK that you have installed.

> knowing that I only want to use the JDK 7 to run some java project ?

The Java 7 JDK is backwards compatible, meaning it should run all existing java apps.

If you were worried about swapping between Java 6&7 then this thread may help: https://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2

Comment: thanks for your response. Since I am extensively using `chrome`, is it possible to let `java 1.6` run as default, and set the `JDK 7` only when choosing the `SDK` of my IDE projects ?

Comment: Yes it is. I have only needed to swap it on windows before so I am not sure of the specifics on OSX, but the link below shows you how to change the java_home directory, so if you install the JDK, then set java_home to the OLD jre directory then everything should run as it was before installing the JDK: http://superuser.com/a/555749

Comment: Alternately if you could just get your hands on the JDK 7 folder, then you would not need to install it, and that way you are not altering the existing java setup, so crome will work as normal, and you just need to specify the JDK 7 path in your IDE when you need to use it.

Comment: Do you know where I can find this folder ?

Comment: I dont know where to find one, there is no official source. I would install it on another machine and copy it over. Or you could install it, then copy the folder, then remove it (and just reinstall your old java version to make sure its setup properly). I know its a lot of messing around but I don't know of any other good work around.

Comment: About installing the JDK on a brand new MacBook Pro, I had the same problem. Downloading it from Firefox seems to have worked. Google Chrome seems to be failing more and more....

Answer (score 0):

You can download on another system. And unzip the contents to a folder. Then you can copy that onto your Mac and try. I guess that is what he meant by the folder.